# How to not create a key in an object?

Tags: javascript

How to create a key conditionally while the object is being defined? (I know it is possible because someone did it before and I forgot how...)

```
var where = {
  wid: 123,
  pid: 321
}

var superwhere = {
  wid: where.wid,
  pid: where.pid,
  pageid: where.pageid || 'something here I forgot'
}
```

And the output of superwhere should be:

```
{
  wid: 123,
  pid: 321
}
```

Basically something similar to:

```
var where = {
  wid: 123,
  pid: 321
}

var superwhere = {
  wid: where.wid,
  pid: where.pid,
}

if (where.pageid) {
  superwhere.pageid = where.pageid
}
```

Comment: Either I need coffee or the question is really unclear. Please explain what are you trying to achieve. That way we can relate to question and probably help you

Comment: Can you please elaborate the goal? "_not create a key in an object_" can be easily achieved by avoiding to assign a property, i.e. don't write it, but that's probably not an answer you need ..?

Comment: @Rajesh looks like OP is asking if it is possible to create a key conditionally  while the object is being defined.

Comment: I've got no idea what you are trying to ask, please clarify your question with more code.

Comment: @gurvinder372 exactly

Comment: @AeroWang I guess best way is to use the code you have. Definition usually do not have any conditional flow. Its a simple assignment.

Comment: It has to be somewhere else (if possible at all), you've already created a key when the logical or is executed in your example.

Comment: @RobG it outputs 'something here I forgot'...

Comment: @AeroWang—yes, I finally understood you're trying to conditionally create the property. You can't do that in an initializer.

Comment: maybe you want to use the ternary operator: condition ? true : false; [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: @angel9215—more like `where.pageid && (superWhere.pageid = where.pageid);`, but that can't go in an initializer.

Comment: Not exactly what you need, but you could use computed property names, and set property name to empty string, if a condition will not pass. Ex. `x = {[condition ? 'propName' : '']: prop_value};` Doesn't work in strict mode if more than one conditionally set propertynames is needed (an empty string is a valid prop name, hence the property is actually created).

Answer (score 1):

You can use object spread

```js
var where = {
  wid: 123,
  pid: 321
}

var superwhere = {pageid:"something here I forgot", ...where};

console.log(superwhere);
```

or `Object.assign()`

```js
var where = {
  wid: 123,
  pid: 321,
  pageid: 456
}

var superwhere = Object.assign({pageid:"something here I forgot"}, where);

console.log(superwhere);
```

Comment: I think this is the closest one can get with one single assignment statement +1

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Classes which are supported in ES6.

Typically Classes can enumerate JSON objects with conditions through a function. You can observe this through the following class and instance of a class.

```
class Conditional {
  generateJSON(n) {
    if (n == true) {
      return {
        'key1': 'hello',
        'key2': 'world'
      }
    } else {
      return {
        'key1': 'hello'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, since the question was not clear. We need a more clear definition of what you're looking for.